# How can I find more information about mvn "Unknown error trying to execute the external compiler

Tags: maven, compiler-errors

How can I investigate mvn **Unknown error trying to execute the external compiler**? 
According to compiler-plugin source in this case javac returns nonzero but mvn can't extract error information (alas mvn appears to eat the javac error code in this situation)- [JavacCompiler.Java](http://svn.codehaus.org/plexus/plexus-components/trunk/plexus-compiler/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java).  I know that Mvn has issues parsing java 7 output and I tried running java manually but I can't reproduce the error.

I'm using mvn303, compiler plugin 2.5.1 and java 1.7 07.

- mvn clean compile -X - **fails with error**
- copy paste mvn's failed /bin/sh for javac invocation - **sh+javac completes without an error code**

Let me know if you have any ideas on how to handle this situation.

Thanks

Peter

`[ERROR] /bin/sh -c cd /myproj/modules/memory && /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/../bin/javac @/myproj/modules/memory/target/classes/org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler4013958444740287519arguments -J-Xmx512m -J-Xms512m
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project memory: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    ...
    ...

org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileOutOfProcess(JavacCompiler.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:157)`

Comment: Can you show the appropriate parts of the pom?

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out it was a resource issue blocking JVM fork and javac invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the cause of the problem - no memory for the fork.  We had java processes in the background and set the compiler plugin to fork.  When maven attempted fork it failed resulting in an error code but no error information (at least none that the plugin could understand).

FYI, I think there's an improvement we can make to the JavaCompiler code.  At present a failure with no message yields a generic error statement.  However, we do have a returnCode and could add this to the text providing a few more bread crumbs to follow when we hit this kind of case.

```
        if ( ( returnCode != 0 ) && messages.isEmpty() )
                {
                    if ( err.getOutput().length() == 0 )
                    {
                        throw new CompilerException( "Unknown error trying to execute the external compiler: " + EOL
                            + cli.toString() );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        messages.add( new CompilerError( "Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:" + EOL
                            + err.getOutput(), true ) );
                    }
                }
```